# datepicker elements raising undefined or null reference in Internet Explorer only

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, datepicker, undefined-reference

I'm getting error shown below with a couple of datepicker elements I have in my form, every time I run it using Internet Explorer (different versions):

```
Unhandled exception at line 393, column 4 in http://localhost/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference
```

This is the code containing the elements definition, is important to mention that the error raises  only when Submit button is pressed when using any Internet Explorer version (it works fine with Firefox):

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Dashboard = "";
    ViewBag.Item = "";
    ViewBag.Events = "active";
    ViewBag.Location = "";
}

<div class="container">
       @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EventDetails", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "eventDetails", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input name="equipmentCode" class="form-control" type="text" value="Scan Equipment" onfocus="if(this.value=='Scan Equipment') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Scan Equipment';}" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="$(this.form).submit();">Submit</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 text-center" style="padding-top: 7px">Completed Date between:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-2"><input name="dtStart" class="form-control datepicker" /></div>
                <label class="text-center col-lg-1" style="padding-top: 7px">and:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-2"><input name="dtEnd" class="form-control datepicker" /></div>
            </div>
    </div>
    }





    <div class="row">
        @*<div id="itemDetails" class="col-sm-12"> Commented by Rod*@
        <div id="EventDetails" class="col-sm-12">
            @RenderBody()
            @*            @Html.Partial("PartialViews/_Item", Model)*@
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the code within the _Events.cshtml that is initializing the datepicker():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $('.datepicker').datepicker();});
</script>
```

I'd appreciate any help here, since I'm tempted to remove entirely this DatePicker component..

Comment: You are showing server side code, the exception is occurring in bootstrap-datepicker.js which you have not provided here.

Comment: The code can be downloaded from here:[link]http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: I found a workaround for this issue, in case any of you get it someday.The problem is that the dtStart and dtEnd elements were invoking the datepicker() by class name as shown below:

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () { $('.datepicker').datepicker();});
    </script>

what I did is adding an ID to the dtStart and dtEnd elements and invoke them by ID instead of class in the next way instead:

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $('#dtStart').datepicker(); $('#dtEnd').datepicker(); });
    </script>

With that the issue is gone in IE.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for this issue, in case any of you get it someday.

The problem is that the dtStart and dtEnd elements were invoking the datepicker() by class name as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $('.datepicker').datepicker();});
</script>
```

what I did is adding an ID to the dtStart and dtEnd elements and invoke them by ID instead of class in the next way instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { $('#dtStart').datepicker(); $('#dtEnd').datepicker(); });
</script>
```

In theory it should work in both ways, but with this the issue is gone and it works for all browsers now..

Comment: Dang. This describes my problem exactly, but I have at least a dozen dates in my form.

Comment: You can do it like this: `$('input[type=date]').each(function(e){ $(e).datepicker(); });`